# XML to Linq value from childnode from same parents are together

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have written linq code so I can read childnodes from the a parent node. I m getting the both the child node values, but it appear as one long string. How to split the values?

This is my XML calling function:

```
    var wsinputs = new List<string>();
     wsinputs = readXMLInput(2);
```

This is my function:

```
    public List<string> readXMLInput(int seq)
    {

        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXX\selection.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> selectedServiceList = xelement.Elements();


        var inputtype = new List<string>();

        int countnum = selectedServiceList.Descendants("seq").Count();

        // for (int x = 1; x <= countnum; x++)
        //  {

        IEnumerable<string> serviceinputs = from servinput in xelement.Elements("Service")
                                            let inp = (string)servinput.Element("inputs")
                                            orderby inp
                                   //         where (string)servinput.Element("seq") == seq.ToString()
                                            select inp;

        foreach (string zp in serviceinputs)
        {
            inputtype.Add(zp);

        }

        //}

        return inputtype;
    }
```

This is the output i get:

```
System.IntSystem.Int
```

I need to get :

```
System.Int
System.Int
```

The node values should be separated.

This is my xml:

```
<SelectedService>
<Service>
 <servicename>updatemapInt</servicename>
 <seq>1</seq>
 <serviceURL>http://XXX.XXXX.net/Service1.svc?wsdl</serviceURL>
<inputs>
 <input>System.Int</input>
 <input>System.Int</input>
 </inputs>
 <Output>System.String</Output>
 </Service>
<Service>
```

Comment: Shouldn't inserting a space character when printing `wsinputs` help?

Comment: how to add?  This line of code puts it together. It adds as one. i dont know how to split it. 

 foreach (string zp in serviceinputs)
        {
            inputtype.Add(zp);

        }

Comment: Your `List<string>` contains values you want to print. It does not contain space or new line characters. You have to inject them when printing these elements. How do you print `readXMLInput()` return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can call `ToList()` to have the LINQ query return `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. Then for the main question, you can either use double `form` clause like so :

```
List<string> serviceinputs = (from service in xelement.Elements("Service")
                              from servinput in service.Element("inputs").Elements("input")
                              let inp = (string)servinput
                              orderby inp
                              select inp).ToList();
```

Or modify the single `from` clause to return individual `<input>` value separately :

```
List<string> serviceinputs = (from servinput in xelement.Elements("Service")
                                                        .Elements("inputs")
                                                        .Elements("input")
                              let inp = (string)servinput
                              orderby inp
                              select inp).ToList();
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/miz1uB)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
System.Int
System.Int
```

Comment: This Works: 

List<string> serviceinputs = (from servinput in xelement.Elements("Service")
                                          where (string)servinput.Element("seq") == x.ToString()
                                          from inputs in servinput.Elements("inputs").Elements("input")
                                          orderby inputs.Value
                                          select inputs.Value).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

When you do `servinput.Element("inputs")`, you get at once all the content of the node `<inputs>` (that's why you get the `System.IntSystem.Int` single string as output). In order to get the `<input>` nodes separated, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> serviceinputs = from inputs in xelement.Elements("Service")
                                                           .Elements("inputs")
                                                           .Elements("input")
                                    orderby inputs.Value
                                    select inputs.Value;
```

If you want to do some more filtering, you can do it easily:

```
IEnumerable<string> serviceinputs = from servinput in xelement.Elements("Service")
                                    where (string)servinput.Element("seq") == seq.ToString()
                                        from inputs in servinput.Elements("inputs").Elements("input")
                                        orderby inputs.Value
                                        select inputs.Value;
```